# multiple where clauses

Tags: sql, oracle

I have the following table:

```
 ID    Key   Value
 1     From  x
 1     To    Y
 1     CC    a
 2     From  Z
 2     To    X
 2     CC    b
 3     From  X
 3     To    Y  
 3     CC    c
 4     From  X
 4     To    Z
 4     CC    d
```

I want Id 1 and 3 as result such that where key =" From " and value = "x " and  where key =" To " and value = "Y " (From->To should be x->y)
It should be something like this

```
SELECT Id
FROM table_name
WHERE REGEXP_LIKE(KEY, '(^|\s)from(\s|$)', 'i')
    AND REGEXP_LIKE(value, '(^|\s)x(\s|$)', 'i')
    AND
WHERE
WHERE REGEXP_LIKE(KEY, '(^|\s)to(\s|$)', 'i')
    AND REGEXP_LIKE(value, '(^|\s)y(\s|$)', 'i')
```

Is it possible to  solve this problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using conditional `SUM`

[**SqlFiddleDemo**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/d43d1/3)

```
SELECT ID
FROM Table1
GROUP BY ID
HAVING 
      SUM(CASE WHEN "Key" = 'From' and LOWER("Value") = 'x' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) = 1 
 AND  SUM(CASE WHEN "Key" = 'To' and LOWER("Value") = 'y' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) = 1
```

**OUTPUT**

```
| ID |
|----|
|  1 |
|  3 |
```

Comment: Will this  also work when I have multiple To's?   Please See my question below.

Comment: Yes, my solution work for multiple To's. Maybe you would like to change `THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) >= 1 ` In case you have `X->(Y , Y)` You can also try modify the SqlFiddle. use the `Text to DDL` function to load the table with new data.

Comment: No, Incase of multiple To's , It returns only Id " 3 "but I want 1 and 3 since both has X->Y .  see this link.  http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/d43d1/6

Comment: Priya your fiddle doesnt have `LOWER("Value")`, you have some `x` lower case and other uppercase `X`

Comment: Remember upvote and accept this answer if help you with your problem

Answer (score 0):

Join the table to itself and filter accordingly.

```
    SELECT ID
    FROM 
            Table t1
            INNER JOIN Table t2
            ON t1.ID = t2.ID
    WHERE
            t1.Key = 'From' AND
            t1.Value = 'x' AND
            t2.Key = 'To' AND
            t2.Value = 'y'
```

Comment: Thanks rabbit:) Let me try!